# IIS7, Image Quality 100

Tags: .net, image, image-processing, iis-7

We have an application that receives images via thumb drive and uploads the images to a central server through a service. Originally the defaults was to set the quality of the image to 92 and resize the image down from the original.  The enhancement is to allow that to be configured.

We are testing the changes and find that when the image quality is set to 100 it can make the local backup without a problem but cannot transfer the image, we get an error abort message from the service.  When we put the image at original size but back to 92 no problem. One some computers we can move the quality to 96 others 95, anything above that produces the error.

This is our code on setting the quality of the image and saving to a local directory before transfer.

```
EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
```

Here is our binding in the client config file.

```
<binding name="basicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" 
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
             maxBufferSize="524288000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" messageEncoding="Text" 
             textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="524288000" 
                    maxArrayLength="524288000" maxBytesPerRead="524288000" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="524288000" />
    <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

These images are around 2 meg images so http request size is not a factor.

Any ideas on where I should be looking.  The process works, so it is a setting or a limitation within IIS7 or .NET.

Comment: "we get an error abort message from the service." get a stack trace of this error and share it with us as well as the relevant source code lines. Also check to make sure the locally stored image files with 100% quality are not corrupted, can you inspect them with an image viewer?

Comment: The error we get is The request was aborted: The request was canceled. occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel. This is telling me that the request is failing before any code that we have written has been executed. Non of logging is being trigger. As far as the images corrupted, No, or else I would have expected it to fail regardless of a 96 or 95 quality. I can view the images in a viewer. The workaround was to get the max length of the image & resize the image to the current length, then send everything worked. Do not know what that did 2 alter the image. The net resize is 0.